# Executing Javascript functions by reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I'm wondering if any of yall have any insight as to how one could execute a function by reference in javascript.

http://mootools.net/shell/yL93N/1/

Any discussion would be cool.

-Chase

Comment: damn that moo shell is awesome, thx for the link - bookmarked.

Comment: if you like mooshell check http://www.jsfiddle.net - same engine (done by zalun/mootools team) but with support of multiple frameworks

Comment: Yeah JSfiddle is a REALLY cool site.  We use it all the time to colab on simple functions and for testing.  But when you want to show support for the best JS library out there, you gotta link to MooShell.

Comment: mooshell is slower for me (i am based in london) so i prefer jsfiddle (uk hosting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at your mooshell, the way i'd handle it in mootools is this:

http://mootools.net/shell/yL93N/10/

```
var proxyFunction = new Class({
    message: "hello",
    Binds: ['passByReference','sayit'],
    passByReference: function(func) {
        // console.log(this, this[func]);
        if (this[func] && $type(this[func]) === "function")
            this[func]();
    },
    sayit: function() {
        alert(this.message);
    },
    killit: function() {
        document.write('we\'re dead');
    }
});

$('tryit').addEvent('change',function(e){
    new proxyFunction().passByReference(this.get('value'));
});

// or have a permanent proxy instance if you call methods of the class often and need it to change things.

var proxy = new proxyFunction();
$('tryit').addEvent('change',function(e){
    proxy.passByReference(this.get('value'));
});
```

the advantage of doing so is that all your proxied functions are behind a common object, don't pollute your window namespace as global variables and can share data that relates to the event.

Comment: My plan is to use this system to switch between "Template" classes to populate a div.  And like you said, No one wants to muddy their Window obj.

Answer (score 1):

Globally-defined functions (and variables) are visible as members of the global `window` object.

Members of an object can be fetched by name using the square bracket notation: `o['k']` is the same as `o.k`. So, for your example:

```
var function_name= $(this).val();
window[function_name]();
```

Comment: This seems to be the accepted solution,  or function = []; function['name']=function(){}; ish.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you mean, but you can do this:

```
var func = window.alert;
var args = ["hello world"]
func.apply(window, args)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
function blah() {
...do stuff
}

myref = blah

myref()
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to do:

```
func.call();
```

Answer (score 0):

Function variables in JavaScript already are references. If you have a function:

```
var explode = function() { alert('boom!'); };
```

You can pass `explode` around as an argument, and it's only passing a handle to that function, not the entire function body.

For proof of this, try:

```
explode.id = 5;
var detonate = explode;
alert(detonate.id); // => 5
explode.id = 6;
alert(detonate.id); // => 6
```

Answer (score 0):

functions are first class objects in Java Script. Effectively this means that you can treat it very much as if it were a variable, and pass it anywhere that you would expect a variable.

e.g.

```
var myFn = function() { alert('inside anonymous fn'); }

function callMyFn(paramFn) 
{
  paramFn();
}

callMyFn(myFn); //inside anonymous fn

function MyFnHolders(argFn)
{
  this.argFn = argFn;
  this.fieldFn = function() {
    alert('inside fn field');
  }
}

var myFnHolders = new MyFnHolders(myFn);
myFnHolders.argFn();   //'inside anonymous fn'
myFnHolders.fieldFn(); //'inside fn field'

//etc
```

so passing a function by ref can be done simply by assigning it to a variable and passing it around.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one with a closure for your arguments...

```
function Runner(func, args) {
  return function() { return func.apply(window, args); };
}

var ref = new Runner(window.alert, ["hello world"]);
ref();
```